# Apache Tomcat - back and forth stream

Tags: java, tomcat, stream

I have a java client and a few Tomcat servers - Web servers. I have a sequence of operations I have to perform on the same server.
What I have in mind is using the same tcp-session, using a chain of:
 read, write, read, write... - on server side
 write, read, write, read... - on client side

Problem - after a read, write on the tomcat server - the next read get a -1 or EOFException.

client code:

```
    java.net.URL u = new URL("http", "127.0.0.1", 8080, "/Dyno/BasicServlet");
    HttpUrlConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
    huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
    huc.setDoOutput(true);
    huc.connect();
    os = huc.getOutputStream();
    byte[] b = info();
    os.write(b)
    os.flush();
    is = huc.getInputStream();
    byte[] b2 = new byte[10];
    is.read(b2);
    byte[] b = info(b2);
    os.write(b)
```

Server code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletInputStream is = request.getInputStream();
    ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] clientMsg = new byte[10];
is.read(clientMsg);
    serverMsg = respond(clientMsg);
    os.write(serverMsg)
    os.flush();
    is.read(); //Here I get -1
```

My theory is that Tomcat is closing the stream.
Do you agree? 
Anyway to get bypass this?

Thank you.

Comment: I think once you flushed the response the request is no more valid.

Comment: unique to servlets? back-and-forth does work on sockets.

Comment: No its a http issue: request -> response -> done. request -> response -> done. Whats are you actually trying to archive?

Comment: I want to incorporate SSO. For that I need a request->response->reques->... - otherwise the authentication process will have to start again if the client is redirected to another server.

Comment: Have a look at "sticky session"-mode. That makes sure, a client, having a valid http session, is always redirected to the same server.

Comment: I'm familiar with this - I don't want to rely on it. anyway of getting raw socket underneath?

Comment: Hm I don't get it yet. So you have several servers but no cluster config? For sure you can create raw sockets in you web app, by using a ServletListener, for example. But you might be reinventing the wheel? What about using rmi or a webservice to communicate to the server?

Comment: -system already built -the sticky bit is something i don't want to depend on

Comment: Maybe you can use WebSockets? I don't know if the underlying socket is kept intact during the entire conversation.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is request-response only.
But WebSockets allow for full duplex communications between client and server.

Apache Tomcat 7 has preliminary support for WebSockets.